# Select2 JQuery didn't work in IIS server (locally ) but working in development environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, iis-6

I face an issue with select drop-down ASP core to be searchable its working fine in the development environment, but when  I have published the app to the IIS server it does not work
as I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glr8X.png) have attached

look at the published website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zodjl.png)

below are the CSS and Jquery code

```
<link href="JQ/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="JQ/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="JQ/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Damage').select2();

    });
```

please assist .

Comment: errors in console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check ur development  server scripts location. The code looks good.